# Using a number that is smaller then 1

Tags: xcode, swift

Hei, I am trying my first steps in Swift coding, and I am trying to build a calculator. It should divide things though 0.5 for example, but I am getting a error message because it cant read 0.5 just full digits like 5. How can I enter number that are smaller then 1? I am very thankful for help! here is my code:

```
@IBAction func findBudget(sender: AnyObject) {


    var enteredBudget = enterBudget.text.toInt ()

    var myBudget = enteredBudget! / 0.5


    resultMy.text = "My Budget: \(myBudget)"


}
```

Comment: You need to use Doubles not Integers

Comment: Thanks. Do you have an idea how that looks in that coding?

Comment: Actually you should use `NSDecimalNumber` or you will have rounding problems since many decimal numbers such as 0.7 can't be represented exactly in floating point numbers.

Comment: But how would the code look? where do I define NSDecimalNumber?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can covert your `Int` to a `Double`:

```
var myBudget = Double(enteredBudget!) / 0.5
```

Comment: @Tim Lewis Thanks for polish up my answer, now I know how to do it right ;) But why did you lowercase int and double?

Comment: No problem, and sorry, habit from a different language. I can change that back for ya. My bad :P

Comment: is there a possibility to just show the result before the point? like 2432 instead od 2342.231004

Comment: Covert it back to an 'Int'  `Int(myBudget) `

Comment: Sorry, i just learn to format my answers here at Stackoverflow. Hit enter and send my answer without code.

Comment: strange nothing changes, I put in: `var myBudget = Double(enteredBudget!) / 0.5 Int(myBudget)`

Comment: Make a new Variable or Constant `var newInteger = Int(myBudget)` and use this.

Comment: you are welcome! Maybe you could vote my answer as accepted by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: to do this i need 15 reputation :(

Comment: Are you sure? I think you need 15 reputations to vote the answer up or down. There should be an check mark beside my answer that you have to click. But I'm new here too and I haven't asked a question untill now.

Answer (score 0):

You do this by getting the `Double` value from your string rather than an `Int` value. An easy way to do this is to initialize an `NSString` from your text and use its `doubleValue` property, or you could cast it to be an `NSString`.

```
let enteredBudget = NSString(string: textField.text).doubleValue        
let myBudget = enteredBudget / 0.5
println(myBudget)
```